# Problems with backtracking Sudoku Solver [Java]

Tags: java, recursion, sudoku, backtracking

Problem:  Writing a backtracking sudoku solver in Java that takes in a file representing the puzzle, converts it into a matrix, and using recursive backtracking, solves it.

Issue: In my solve method, it will try to solve the first empty box however won't move on past that box.

Error Log:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>     at java.util.AbstractCollection.(AbstractCollection.java:49)
>     at java.util.AbstractList.(AbstractList.java:59)
>     at java.util.ArrayList.(ArrayList.java:108)
>     at java.util.ArrayList.(ArrayList.java:119)
>     at ssolver.solve(ssolver.java:67)
>     at ssolver.solve(ssolver.java:83)
>        at ssolver.solve(ssolver.java:83)
>        ...

Method:

```
public static int[][] solve(int[][]puzzle, int x, int y){
        //using backtracking for brute force power of the gods(norse cause they obviously most b.a.
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //next for both  x and y
        int nextx, nexty=y;

        if(x == 8){
            nextx=0;
            nexty=y+1;
        }
        else{
            nextx=x++;
        }

        if(isSolved(puzzle))
            return puzzle;

        if(!(puzzle[y][x]==0))
            solve(puzzle, nextx, nexty);
        else{
            for(int i =1; i<10; i++){
                if(isTrue(puzzle, y, x, i))
                    list.add(i);
            }   
            for(int i : list){
                puzzle[y][x] = list.get(i);
                printPuzzle(puzzle);//prints here for testing 
                if(isSolved(puzzle)||(x==8&&y==8));
                else{
                    solve(puzzle, nextx, nexty);
                }
            }
        }

        return puzzle;              
    }
```

Could someone point me in the right direction of what is going wrong.  Apologies in advance first time posting if I've done something wrong.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

`StackOverflowError` means that you exceeded the recursion depth limit.

Apparently, using recursion for this problem is **not** a good idea.

Implementing such a code wuithout recursion is harder, but you don't have any other choice.

You can get some inspiration in the article [Replace Recursion with Iteration](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceRecursionWithIteration.html)

Comment: It's having problems after the first recursion, I have it printing the current state of the puzzle during each recursion

Comment: can't this be the pitfall? `if(!(puzzle[y][x]==0))
            solve(puzzle, nextx, nexty);` ? It's in different branch than where you print it.

Comment: i use that merely to move on to the next space if there is already a value in that space.  the example test case I use has a number in the first block, which it skips over properly, to double check that works however it is worth looking into more.

Comment: make a `private static int recDepth = 0`, and to the beginning of the solve method, add `System.out.println("RecDepth = " + recDepth++);`. I think you will be surprised what you get there.

Answer (score 0):

note that the sudoko puzzle will need a depth of about 9*9=81 for this to work, so it might be an overkill.

another reason is that you check all possible numbers, so it's 9^9=387,420,489 possible combinations.

you should at least add a function isValid for the puzzle, to avoid running invalid "branches" and going deeper with them.

in order to efficiently solve it , you should make it iterable, and also put for each cell the possible numbers that you can use.

[here's a link](http://www.wikihow.com/Solve-a-Sudoku) of how solving sudoko can work (look at number 4). after putting all of the numbers for each cell, all you have to do is to go step by step and eliminate numbers according to logic.

only after all logic rules were used, use the recursion method (or itereation). this will make your algorithm much more efficient and faster than any other backtracking algorithm.

Comment: ok, that makes sense.  as for the isValid method, the isTrue(puzzle, y, x, [possible]) checks the column, row, and square to validate that the number will work, i believe that is what you mean.  full code is at github under wechtera/ssolverOO in the ssolver.java file

Comment: yes , the isTrue should work, but you've made it way more complicated than what it could be (in the functions that it uses), so i can't understand what you did there. you didn't have to use so many loops,especially for rows and columns checks.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm employed is similar to the standard backtracking used to solve the eight queens puzzle, seen here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle

Here is a class provided by Bob Carpenter (http://www.colloquial.com/carp)

This code example helped me solve the very same issue of backtrack solving of a sudoku game.
After a little investigation I was able to recode it to fit my program.

Please message back if you are having trouble understanding the logics of this code.

The following code is directly copy pasted from his source code.

```
/**
 * The <code>Sudoku</code> class povides a static <code>main</code>
 * method allowing it to be called from the command line to print the
 * solution to a specified Sudoku problem.
 *
 * <p>The following is an example of a Sudoku problem:
 *
 * <pre>
 * -----------------------
 * |   8   | 4   2 |   6   |
 * |   3 4 |       | 9 1   |
 * | 9 6   |       |   8 4 |
 *  -----------------------
 * |       | 2 1 6 |       |
 * |       |       |       |
 * |       | 3 5 7 |       |
 *  -----------------------
 * | 8 4   |       |   7 5 |
 * |   2 6 |       | 1 3   |
 * |   9   | 7   1 |   4   |
 *  -----------------------
 * </pre>
 *
 * The goal is to fill in the missing numbers so that
 * every row, column and box contains each of the numbers
 * <code>1-9</code>.  Here is the solution to the
 * problem above:
 *
 * <pre>
 *  -----------------------
 * | 1 8 7 | 4 9 2 | 5 6 3 |
 * | 5 3 4 | 6 7 8 | 9 1 2 |
 * | 9 6 2 | 1 3 5 | 7 8 4 |
 *  -----------------------
 * | 4 5 8 | 2 1 6 | 3 9 7 |
 * | 2 7 3 | 8 4 9 | 6 5 1 |
 * | 6 1 9 | 3 5 7 | 4 2 8 |
 *  -----------------------
 * | 8 4 1 | 9 6 3 | 2 7 5 |
 * | 7 2 6 | 5 8 4 | 1 3 9 |
 * | 3 9 5 | 7 2 1 | 8 4 6 |
 *  -----------------------
 * </pre>
 *
 * Note that the first row <code>187492563</code> contains
 * each number exactly once, as does the first column
 * <code>159426873</code>, the upper-left box
 * <code>187534962</code>, and every other row, column
 * and box.
 *
 * <p>The {@link #main(String[])} method encodes a problem as an array
 * of strings, with one string encoding each constraint in the problem
 * in row-column-value format.  Here is the problem again with
 * the indices indicated:
 *
 * <pre>
 *     0 1 2   3 4 5   6 7 8
 *    -----------------------
 * 0 |   8   | 4   2 |   6   |
 * 1 |   3 4 |       | 9 1   |
 * 2 | 9 6   |       |   8 4 |
 *    -----------------------
 * 3 |       | 2 1 6 |       |
 * 4 |       |       |       |
 * 5 |       | 3 5 7 |       |
 *   -----------------------
 * 6 | 8 4   |       |   7 5 |
 * 7 |   2 6 |       | 1 3   |
 * 8 |   9   | 7   1 |   4   |
 *    -----------------------
 * </pre>
 *
 * The <code>8</code> in the upper left box of the puzzle is encoded
 * as <code>018</code> (<code>0</code> for the row, <code>1</code> for
 * the column, and <code>8</code> for the value).  The <code>4</code>
 * in the lower right box is encoded as <code>874</code>.
 *
 * <p>The full command-line invocation for the above puzzle is:
 *
 * <pre>
 * % java -cp . Sudoku 018 034 052 076 \
 *                     113 124 169 171 \
 *                     209 216 278 284 \
 *                     332 341 356     \
 *                     533 545 557     \
 *                     608 614 677 685 \
 *                     712 726 761 773 \
 *                     819 837 851 874 \
 * </pre>
 *
 * <p>See <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku">Wikipedia:
 * Sudoku</a> for more information on Sudoku.
 *
 * <p>The algorithm employed is similar to the standard backtracking
 * <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle">eight
 * queens algorithm</a>.
 *
 * @version 1.0
 * @author <a href="http://www.colloquial.com/carp">Bob Carpenter</a>
 */
public class Sudoku2 {

    /**
     * Print the specified Sudoku problem and its solution.  The
     * problem is encoded as specified in the class documentation
     * above.
     *
     * @param args The command-line arguments encoding the problem.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = parseProblem(args);
        writeMatrix(matrix);
        if (solve(0,0,matrix))    // solves in place
            writeMatrix(matrix);
        else
            System.out.println("NONE");
    }

    static boolean solve(int i, int j, int[][] cells) {
        if (i == 9) {
            i = 0;
            if (++j == 9)
                return true;
        }
        if (cells[i][j] != 0)  // skip filled cells
            return solve(i+1,j,cells);

        for (int val = 1; val <= 9; ++val) {
            if (legal(i,j,val,cells)) {
                cells[i][j] = val;
                if (solve(i+1,j,cells))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        cells[i][j] = 0; // reset on backtrack
        return false;
    }

    static boolean legal(int i, int j, int val, int[][] cells) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 9; ++k)  // row
            if (val == cells[k][j])
                return false;

        for (int k = 0; k < 9; ++k) // col
            if (val == cells[i][k])
                return false;

        int boxRowOffset = (i / 3)*3;
        int boxColOffset = (j / 3)*3;
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k) // box
            for (int m = 0; m < 3; ++m)
                if (val == cells[boxRowOffset+k][boxColOffset+m])
                    return false;

        return true; // no violations, so it's legal
    }

    static int[][] parseProblem(String[] args) {
        int[][] problem = new int[9][9]; // default 0 vals
        for (int n = 0; n < args.length; ++n) {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(args[n].substring(0,1));
            int j = Integer.parseInt(args[n].substring(1,2));
            int val = Integer.parseInt(args[n].substring(2,3));
            problem[i][j] = val;
        }
        return problem;
    }

    static void writeMatrix(int[][] solution) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
            if (i % 3 == 0)
                System.out.println(" -----------------------");
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j) {
                if (j % 3 == 0) System.out.print("| ");
                System.out.print(solution[i][j] == 0
                    ? " "
                    : Integer.toString(solution[i][j]));

                System.out.print(' ');
            }
            System.out.println("|");
        }
        System.out.println(" -----------------------");
    }

}
```